# Is exponentiation to a modulo equivalence preserved?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

That is, if $a = b \pmod n$. Will it be true that $x^a = x^b \pmod n$? If this is true, how can I prove this? Thanks,

Comment: This is not true. Consider $0 \equiv 3 \pmod 3$ but $2^0 \not \equiv 2^3 \pmod 3$.

Comment: That said, by [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), if $a \equiv b \pmod {\phi(n)}$ then $x^a \equiv x^b \pmod n$ for $\gcd (x,n)= 1$.

Comment: If you have a perfect power that has to be calculated mod n , you can reduce the base mod n and if the result is non-zero, you can then reduce the exponent mod $\varphi(n)$ without changing the result. Sometimes  , the chinese remainder theorem also helps to find out the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the statement is not true.

However, there is a related true statement ([Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)):

> If $a\equiv b\pmod{\varphi(n)}$, then $x^a\equiv x^b\pmod{n}$ given that $x$ and $n$ are coprime.

Here $\varphi$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).